# Not able to parse data combination of JSON as well as XML (Invalid JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, xml

Value I am getting from source is : something like this
combination of JSON as well as XML (Invalid JSON)

```
{"status":"success","statusCode":"200","result":[{"type":"abc","details":{"ax":{"value":"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"},"tag":"jhgjg","jhgdj":{"khdjh":"no","value":"nhdhghgd","conf":90},"mother":{"value":"","conf":0}},"checksum":"jddkhjkdh"}]}
```

Which is not valid JSON, Even no any modification is possible at source end.
Though it is so, how can I Parse the data.?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to escape those double quotes, something like:

```js
let json = '{"status":"success","statusCode":"200","result":[{"type":"abc","details":{"ax":{"value":"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"},"tag":"jhgjg","jhgdj":{"khdjh":"no","value":"nhdhghgd","conf":90},"mother":{"value":"","conf":0}},"checksum":"jddkhjkdh"}]}'
  .replace(/version="/, "version=\\\"")
  .replace(/" encoding="/, "\\\" encoding=\\\"")
  .replace(/\"\?>/, "\\\"?>");

console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could escape the quotes as Luis Ramalho suggests, but why do things the easy way?  (:

Here, I've isolated everything inside the `< >` tags and replaced the double quotes with single quotes.

```js
let data = '{"status":"success","statusCode":"200","result":[{"type":"abc","details":{"ax":{"value":"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"},"tag":"jhgjg","jhgdj":{"khdjh":"no","value":"nhdhghgd","conf":90},"mother":{"value":"","conf":0}},"checksum":"jddkhjkdh"}]}';

const bracketRange = [data.indexOf('<'), data.indexOf('>')];

let tag = data.slice(bracketRange[0], bracketRange[1] + 1);

const quote = /"/g;

tag = tag.replace(quote, "'");

const beginning = data.slice(0, bracketRange[0] - 1);
const ending = data.slice(bracketRange[1] + 1, data.length);

data = beginning + tag + ending;

console.log(data);
```